# Juniper firmware upgrade MX80/480 and 960 junos 11.4R7>>>13.3R9

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

Ive been tasked with writing the SOP along with implementing the above task of upgrading our core/aggregation and ISP routers in my environment.

We're currently running 11.4R7 and after speaking with our Juniper rep he has advised 13.3R9 would be the best choice.

I have gathered the necessary firmware along with whitepapers and procedures. This will be my first go round with a Juniper upgrade so I am as expected slightly nervous. Im fairly new to Juniper but have years of experience in Cisco environments.

Those of you who have experience in this, what can I expect as far as turn over time per device? Any gotchas you have seen or experience that are worth sharing? Ive read the upgrade guide all 350 pages along with many other things.

Those of you who have done this before what was your methodology for proceeding through the process start to finish?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Fast forward, 9 months or so...Different geographic location, full knowledge of this process, case closed.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have been doing a lots of Junos Upgrade on MX960 and few even bigger stuff like PTX5k or T4k
here is short instruction about MX960
http://ipexptobe.blogspot.com/2016/09/junos-upgrade.html

Maybe this will be usefull

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged because links can go bad after a time, and this site is meant to be an archive. You should include the relevant text in your answer, and include the link for proper attribution.